# How do I quit Android emulator when force quit does not work?

Tags: android, macos, performance, android-studio, mozilla

For me, Android Studio works perfectly fine. I am able to run applications on the Android Studio emulator as well as my genymotion emulator. However, once I decide that I want to close the emulator, it exits, but it stays stuck on my dock. When I try to force quit it with the ALT + COMMAND + ESC dialog, it won't force quit. The emulators also do not show up when I type "top" into the terminal. I'm not sure why this problem persists.

All I want to do is to be able to force quit these icons. I have tried both killall Dock and killall SystemUIServer. Also, the emulators do not show up on my Activity Monitor. It is frustrating because I am still able to open Android Studio and launch new emulators, but they get stuck on my dock.

I am working from a early 2015 Macbook Pro Retina 13-inch. If anyone could offer any help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

[This is the picture of my dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwMFC.png)

Update: other apps seem to quit just fine, but these apps just stay in the dock no matter what. Now, Mozilla Firefox is not quitting as well.

[This is what my dock looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoUiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is third party software, but you could try the freeware program RedQuits:

http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html

It will make it so that clicking the red exit `x` button will close the program instead of dock it.

Comment: I tried the program, and it works for other applications (Chrome, Messages, etc.), but when I try to use it on the Android emulator, it does not work.